# Data Source Exception: Internet communication error: SSL connect error in TABLEAU

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

We started to get failed messages when refreshing extracts based on Bigquery
When looking at the error in the TABLEAU Server we see the next error:

[image]

Did you encounter a similar problem?
What did you do to sort this out?
Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Looks like the issue described here: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-unable-to-connect-to-the-data-source-ssl-connect-error-opening-google-bigquery-workbook; Cause: Communication with Google BigQuery blocked by firewall or antivirus.

Comment: Assuming this was working for you, then stopped working, it's worth checking that the permissions for the BQ account are still embedded in the workbook. Sometimes refreshing these credentials can resolve issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Big Query API IP being blocked, IT took care

Answer (score 0):

[Resolution](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-unable-to-connect-to-the-data-source-ssl-connect-error-opening-google-bigquery-workbook) from the Tableau Knowledge Base:

As a troubleshooting step, check whether you can access "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery" on the affected computer using an internet browser.

Work with your internal IT to ensure that your firewall or antivirus allows communication to  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery".